# Does Gson have something like @JsonProperty for methods?

Tags: json, jackson, gson

Jackson has the @JsonProperty("name") annotation, which can be applied to methods - the return value of the method will be assigned to the "name" parameter in the JSON.

I found out that Gson has the @SerializedName annotation, but that cannot be used with methods.  Is there any way to get the @JsonProperty functionality for methods in Gson?

Answer (score 47):

Try

> @SerializedName("serialized_fld_name")

Answer (score 16):

The solution in Gson is a similar annotation called `@SerializedName` which you can use to provide names that match the source JSON.

A simple example is shown below:

```
public class Message {
    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("NFd")
    private int fileDescriptors;
}
```

[Source](https://shekhargulati.com/2015/09/14/gson-tip-jsonproperty-equivalent/)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  As I recall, there is a post in the mailing list from a core developer that Gson won't likely be so enhanced, either.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Gson and @SerializedName doesn't help in my case. So I used org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String responseJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```