# How to log the java object as JSON annotated with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization

```
public class Person {
   @JsonProperty("First_Name")
   private String firstName;
}
```

Print this object as json:

```
new Gson().toJson(person);
```

This will log this object as
{"firstName": "S Kumar"}

However, I want to get it logged as `{"First_Name": "S Kumar"}` in the same file where it is getting created.

If it is passed over the network, then the variable will be renamed.
But, how can I log it as changed variable name.

Comment: `@JsonProperty` is a Jackson annotation and would work when using Jackson. Gson ignores it and needs its own so check the [answer from gowridev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64066285/6413377).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use @SerializedName("first_name"). Please refer the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482662/does-gson-have-something-like-jsonproperty-for-methods) & [second link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-rename-the-properties-of-json-using-gson-in-java)